# AT commands long waiting for AT+CMGS result with Huawei E3131 modem

Tags: node.js, at-command

Is it normal that I'm waiting about 30seconds for result from `AT+CMGS="my phone number"\r`

My flow looks like this:

```
REQ: AT
RES: AT
RES: OK

REQ: AT+CMGF=1
RES: AT+CMGF=1
RES: OK

REQ: AT+CMGS="+4xxxxxxxxxx"
RES: AT+CMGS="+4xxxxxxxxxx"
RES: >       <---------- Here I'm waiting around 30-60sec

REQ: My message + 26 char
RES: My message + 26 char
RES: +CMGS: 23 <----------- Here I'm waiting around 5s
RES: OK
```

Is that flow normal? I mean, is it normal that I need to wait such long time for  `>` character?

//EDIT

I'm using Huawei modem E3131 modem

Answer (score 1):

I've found issue:

I had configured `node-serialport` to wait for `\n` char like:

```
serialPort = new SerialPort(port, {
    baudrate: baudrate,
    parser: serialPortRequire.parsers.readline("\n")
});
```

After removing that, it works perfectly.